# Specify max file size while write dataframe as parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

When I try to write a dataframe as parquet, the file sizes are non-uniform. Although I don't want to make the files uniform, I want to set a max size for each file. 
I can't afford to repartition the data as the dataframe is sorted(As per my understanding, repartitioning a sorted dataframe can distort the ordering).

Any help would be appreciated.

I have come across maxRecordsPerFile, but I don't want to limit the number of rows and I might not have full information about the columns(total number of columns and their types). So it's difficult to estimate file size based on rows.
I have read about parquet block size as well and I don't think that helps.